# MAC: How to have the result of a command from Terminal History

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I have a command in terminal a week ago, and for verification purpose, I need to search for this command, and also for the result of it, which have been output in the terminal console 
Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a terminal type

```
cat ~/.bash_history
```

This will show you the history of commands. Assuming you haven't gone beyond the number of commands it stores, you'll find it in there.

You can use the 'more' program to show a page at a time: -

```
cat ~/.bash_history | more
```

If you know the start of the command, such as sudo, you list all sudo commands: -

```
cat ~/.bash_history | grep sudo
```

If you want the result of the command, you'll likely have to run the command again.